How to make my flutter app able to get serial number of my own android device (version android 11) even if additional configuration on the device?
So for my flutter app I need to get the device (real) serial number for device identification reason for my app feature. Android id didn't suffice because if the device get factory reset, it will change and I don't want that. So how do I get the real serial number so even when the device get factory reset it's still the same. Also I don't care if the device need some kind of configuration because it's for internal use anyway. And the device I use is Infinix HOT 12 Play NFC if that relevant.
This is my AndroidManifest.xml file:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.e_ktp_reader">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"
    />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
    />

    <application
        android:label="Sam Online"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
            />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>

I've added READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE permission according to Android Documentation from android documentation that my flutter package refers to and also with below code in dart:
import 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart';

 // ... more imports
 static final DeviceInfoPlugin _deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
 // ... more code
 static Future<String> getSerialNumber() async {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return (await _deviceInfo.androidInfo).serialNumber;
    }

    throw PlatformException(
      code: "UNSUPPORTED",
      message: "Platform is not supported.",
    );
  }

That code called getSerialNumber function from device_info_plus package and still return unknown.
So please help me, what should I do step by step so I can't get serial number in my flutter app from my own android device. Don't care if it needs additional configuration for the device.

For privacy reasons (and to comply with privacy laws in various regions), vendors are making it impossible to get unique device IDs.  Your alternative is to make a UUID and write it into local storage.

I mean I do it for my client's internal usage, so how do I setup my app as a work profile because based on what I read, it needs it
